# How to download the Spacy en_core_web_sm model?

Tags: machine-learning, debugging, nlp, spacy

I ran the command ,

`pip install spacy`

and after that worked fine i ran another command
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

but I am receiving Timeout errors in my terminal saying

```
sock.connect(sa)
```

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 363, in connect
self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D0099E3610>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D0099E3610>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy_*main**.py", line 4, in 
setup_cli()
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli_util.py", line 92, in setup_cli
command(prog_name=COMMAND)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in **call**
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 778, in main
return _main(
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 216, in _main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 683, in wrapper
return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 36, in download_cli
download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 70, in download
compatibility = get_compatibility()
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 94, in get_compatibility
r = requests.get(about.**compatibility**)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 507, in send
raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D0099E3610>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

please help me resolve this issue

i was expeciting the command to execute properly so that i can proceed with my NLP tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear it states:

```
Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out.
```

Probably your side or the server isn't available for some reason. You can download using pip, or download locally and installing.

For manual installation:

```
wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install en_core_web_sm-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Or you can use the `requirements.txt` syntax

```
spacy==3.6.0
en_core_web_sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0/en_core_web_sm-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Lin the requirements.txt part helped me a lot